# Variable in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect, http-status-code-302

i want to redirect my pages whics are ending with the number.
for example:

**www.example.com/content/1213** => **www.example.com/content/sport/1213**

thats ok; but i have pages, ending with the **words** too at the same folder ( www.example.com/content/xxxx )

.htaccess musnt do something to these pages.

i mean:

**www.example.com/content/1213** => **www.example.com/content/sport/1213** OK
**www.example.com/content/xxx** => DO NOTHING

Can i do it with htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in your document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(content)/([0-9]+)$ /$1/sport/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Note: don't forget to enable *mod_rewrite*